# Enable two factor login when logging in to the Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

The link below shows how to enable Multi Factor Authentication (MFA) when logging in to the Azure Portal. Unfortunately the walk through talks about using the classic portal to achieve this. Does anyone know if it possible to enable MFA in the proper portal (portal.azure.com).

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2013/10/09/getting-started-with-windows-azure-multi-factor-authentication/

Comment: If you are using an Azure AD account to sign in, you just enable MFA on that account. There is no portal-specific MFA AFAIK.

Comment: Ahh, yes I see it now thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We can enable MFA via new portal, here is the screenshot, we can follow this steps to enable it.
[image]

Comment: Does this helpful? or what can I do for you?

Comment: Thanks for the info, the response from @juunas actually pointed me in the right direction and I was able to get things going from that. I had a slight issue with accounts created in different AD instances, but other than seems to work fine.